# Want the link of the newly created template folder in google drive to add in the specific cell of google sheet through apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-drive-api, directory-structure

I have a script that creates the client's folder, subfolders, and sheets in the drive whenever I add a new client to the sheet through HTML form. I am looking for a way to add the link in column K for that newly created folder, and also share the link to that folder on the client's email with edit access.

Here is the code that adds template folders in the drive. By the way am new to apps script. So am just learning and taking guidance from experts. Any help is warmly thanked.

```
function createClientAccountFolder(clientNamefolder, costingSheetId, ProposalDocId, renamesheet) {
  // This is the root directory where all the client folders would be stored
  const customerRoot = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder_id');

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var databaseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");
 var lastAvailableRow = databaseSheet.getLastRow();
 const clientName = databaseSheet.getRange(lastAvailableRow, 2).getValue();

 if (clientNamefolder) {
  // This creates the main folder with the customer name
  const clients_sheet = ss.getRange("K2:K" + lastAvailableRow);
  const mainFolder = customerRoot.createFolder(clientNamefolder);
  var folder_url = mainFolder.getUrl();

  // have tried a way to add the link in cell
  clients_sheet.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + mainFolder.getUrl() + '")');

  

  // Creating the sub folders
  // Some are assigned to variables so that later children can be added
  const action_tracker =  mainFolder.createFolder("[SEO] - Action Tracker [" + clientNamefolder + "]")
  const audit =  mainFolder.createFolder("[SEO] - Audits [" + clientNamefolder + "]")
  

  // Creating children
  content.createFolder("[" + clientName +  "] Content Approved")
  content.createFolder("[" + clientName +  "] Content Draft")


  // Getting the documents
  const action_tracker_sheet = DriveApp.getFileById('Sheet_id')
  const analytics_audit = DriveApp.getFileById('Sheet_id')


  // Moving the documents to the respective folders
  const moved_action_tracker_sheet = action_tracker_sheet.moveTo(action_tracker)
  const moved_analytics_audit = analytics_audit.moveTo(audit)
 
  // renamin sheets
  moved_action_tracker_sheet.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().rename(clientName + " Action Tracker");
  moved_analytics_audit.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().rename(clientName + " Analytics Audit");


 } else {
   Logger.log('No Client Name Specified')
 }
}
```

This function is finally triggered to add folder, subfolders, and sheets.

```
function test(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var databaseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");
 var lastAvailableRow = databaseSheet.getLastRow();
 const clientName = databaseSheet.getRange(lastAvailableRow, 2).getValue();
 createClientAccountFolder(clientName, "[SHEET_ID]", "[DOC_ID]")
}
```

Comment: By the way, I have searched a lot from different sources but couldn't find the answer. This might be an easy question but as I am just starting, so can't figure out the solution.

Comment: As your code is currently written, the folder URL should be added to multiple cells, from `K2` to last row. You are not getting that? In that case, can you clarify what you are getting instead? Any error? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by `share the link to that folder on the client's email with edit access`. You mean sharing the folder with the user who is executing the script? Since that same user created the folder, they should have access already. Finally, there's no need to add a formula, you can just set the link as a value, directly: `clients_sheet.setValue(mainFolder.getUrl());`

Comment: "the folder URL should be added to multiple cells, from K2 to last row" yes you are right, the script should add from K2 to the last row. But the problem is, it is even not adding the link in any of the cell, can't figure out why. "can you clarify what you are getting instead?" Not getting any error/value against that, in the logger.log, it says null/undefined. By the way "createClientAccountFolder" function is executed through through "test" function below.

Comment: Share the link to that folder on the client's email with edit access. Basically, clients are added by one user only, with all the details like name/email, not by the clients themselves. So the folder is created by and in that user's drive. So need to share the created folder on that client's mail. I am attaching the link of the folder with sheet images that might help in better understanding. Thank you so much for the time and help. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tn_IRVBBa-k8-ORh6qeQaynuahc5OWr4?usp=sharing

Comment: Where do you get the client's email from? Does it correspond to `clientName`? Also, is it a specific account email address? Or a group email?

Comment: I add them manually. Say I have a new client "A" I am adding his credentials in the sheet through the form shown in the link above like name, email address, website, etc., and all this information is provided by the client himself. the mail is of a specific account, not a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Main issues and solution:

- If you just want to display the link, there's no need to add a formula, you can just set the value directly via [Range.setValue(folderUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).
- If you want the displayed text to be different from the link itself, use the approach taken in [DrDaNkk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146361), via [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value).
- You only want to set the value of a single cell (column K of the last row). Therefore, your range should not include multiple cells, as in your current code (`"K2:K" + lastAvailableRow`), but one, like `"K" + lastRow`.
- In order to share the folder with an email address with edit access, use [Folder.addEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addEditor(String)).

#### Code sample:

```
function addLinkAndShare() {
  const customerRoot = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder_id');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const databaseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients");
  const lastRow = databaseSheet.getLastRow();
  const clientName = databaseSheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  if (clientName) {
    const mainFolder = customerRoot.createFolder(clientNameFolder);
    const folderUrl = mainFolder.getUrl();
    databaseSheet.getRange("K" + lastRow).setValue(folderUrl);
    const clientEmail = databaseSheet.getRange("J" + lastRow).getValue();
    mainFolder.addEditor(clientEmail);
    /*
    / Creating subfolders, renaming, etc. (unrelated to your question)
    */
  } else {
    Logger.log('No Client Name Specified')
  } 
}
```

#### Other issues & improvements:

I'd suggest you to create the folder, add the folder URL and share it on the same script in which the data is appended to the sheet, right before doing that. This way, you can add all values at once and there's no need to retrieve the values that have just been set (e.g. `clientName`), and you'll reduce the amount of calls necessary (see [Minimize calls to other services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)).

Since you didn't provide the code related to the data being appended to the sheet, though, I didn't add that to the code sample above.

Answer (score 1):

I want you to realize you're attempting to add the same folder link to multiple cells in a sheet. I don't know if that's purposeful but I think you might want to change that range. Anyways, my suggested solution uses the [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value) object so you don't have to use a formula. You'll want to change

```
clients_sheet.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + mainFolder.getUrl() + '")');
```

to

```
var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText("Folder URL").setLinkUrl(folder_url).build();
clients_sheet.setRichTextValue(richText);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want the link to be added to a new row whenever a new client is added. A new folder is created every time whenever a new client is added,  want the link of that newly created folder to be added and shared with the clients on their mail which is written in column J.

   const mainFolder = customerRoot.createFolder(clientNamefolder);

This is the line of the code that creates the main folder with the client name. I have also tried your code but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. But thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you want to do then. Perhaps some screenshots from your spreadsheet would help with some comments on what data you want to go where.

Comment: I am really sorry, if for that much difficulty. I am trying my best to communicate it as simply as possible. I am sharing the link to the google drive folder with images in it that might help understand better.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tn_IRVBBa-k8-ORh6qeQaynuahc5OWr4?usp=sharing